# How to add manifest file in war

Tags: java, jar, process, war

I am able to create war file of the dir specified i.e /mydir with

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jar -cvf myapp.war . ",
                        s,
                        new File("/mydir"));
```

but when i try to add manifest file while creating , the war file created is currupted

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jar -cvfm myapp.war MANIFEST.MF . ",
                        s,
                        new File("/mydir"));
```

Even I tried this , it create war but only contains manifest file and not the content of /mydir

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jar -cvfm myapp.war MANIFEST.MF * ",
                        s,
                        new File("/mydir"));
```

Comment: Have you tried this with `jar` instead of `war` ? Is `jar` file created with `manifest.mf` file ? I think u should try for this. When you invoke `jar -cvfm ...` command the `jar` command will add `manifest.mf` file automatically. May be when custom `MANIFEST.MF` is going to add in the created `jar` then it restrict to override the previously created jar. Or you can create `.war` first n then update it to add `manifest.mf` file. Try it.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to create `manifest.mf` file programmatically ? Then **why don't you go with [java.util.jar.Manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/Manifest.html)** ? This class provides you to create customize `manifest` file. You can **specify the attributes which u want to be in generated file using [java.util.jar.Attributes.Name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/Attributes.Name.html).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below snippet and its working fine

```
jar -cvfM  myapp.war MANIFEST.MF * ",
                        s,
                        new File("/mydir"));
```

Which means it will not add manifest autogenerated one rather than it archives the one(customized manifest file) which I have kept in meta-inf folder